# How can I view the contents of my controller pak?

Tags: nintendo-64, gaming-accessories

I have several Nintendo 64 memory paks and I have no idea how to view the contents of each. Is there a startup sequence that works without a game? If I have to view the contents within a game, what games are the best for managing the pak's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/n64/916387-nintendo-64/answers/32900-how-do-i-manage-my-memory-pak), the accepted answer says there is no way of viewing whats on the pak without use of a game. They recommended [Perfect Dark](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_Dark) for managing the pak.

Another answer says to hold start while booting up the Nintendo 64.  Another recommends holding `B`. I would at least try that I suppose since it's easy, but it likely won't work.

Comment: What does holding b do?

Comment: According that the thread linked in my post, it allows you to access the paks contents, but I doubt that it works.  I was just including the information that other users have tried.

Comment: I have a working n64, but I don't have a pak, I would test it if I could

Comment: Holding the A button could be done on the Gamecube which had a "BIOS" program for managing memory cards. Holding the B button on the Gamecube would enable High resolution mode if supported. The N64 doesn't have any similar software built-in. The only firmware it has is for system initialization, some of which is included in every Game Cartridge.

Answer (score 6):

In the N64 era, there was a requirement that every game that had compatibility with the controller pack must have a menu to manage the controller pack's data.

In most games that are compatible with the controller pack, you can:

1. Hold start on boot-up to bring up one of these menu before the game starts like normal.

However, there are games that did not utilize this feature that are exceptions to this. For these games:

2. There's an option in the game menus.

How you reach such menu differs by game, but there should always be one. If you have problem you can always look in the instruction manual but <sub><sup>who does</sup></sub> <sub><sup><sub><sup>that anyway?</sup></sub></sup></sub>